# Set request to django model object?

Tags: python, django

I want to write a render function for a model which takes a template_name and renders its attributes with the loaded template.  So you can call {{ model_object.render }} to retrieve it's template string.  However, I need to be able to pass in a request object to the model object to have all the necessary data.

I don't want to use a weird template hack to pass in a request object to the render function nor do I want to use a queryset function to loop through the queryset and attach a request object to each object.  Is there another way to add a request object to a model object in a queryset?

Comment: it's not a good idea to do anything request-related in your models

Comment: There is no weird template hack in writing a template tag that does this for you. And +1 to what @Alp said.

Comment: Second the above two, except I would say create a filter and pass the model and some other variable if needed to it. Like @Bibhas said, this is not a hack. It's out of the box Django functionality.

Comment: @Alp can you explain why?

Comment: Because Django follows the MVC approach, where models are separated from application logic used to generating the view. If you pass request objects to the model, you break with that principle and will go to programmers hell.